# I have this problemstatement (given below) and when I test it against (for example) an input 30, the answer should be 6. But I'm getting 0. Why?

Tags: c

Given a positive integer N, find the number of positive integer divisors of N^2 that are less than N, but do not divide N. Constraints: 1<=N<=(10^12)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    float N;
    scanf("%f",&N);

    float nsq = N*N;
    float i;
    int count = 0;

    for(i=1.0f; i<N; i=i+1.0f)
    {
        if(fmodf(nsq,i))

        {
            count++;
            if(fmodf(N,i))
                count--;
        }
    }

    printf("%d", count);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Rather than asking stackoverflow to debug your code for you, you would be better learning to do it yourself. For example, inside your loop, print out the value of i, whether your code determines if it is/isn't a factor of N^2, and whether it is/isn't a factor of N. Then see what looks wrong and you may get an idea of which part of your code is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If the remainder is zero then the object is divisible, but the if statements won't be taken as the `0.0f` value is regarded as false.

You must compare the results of functions fmodf wtih 0:

```
if(fmodf(nsq,i) == 0.0f)
```

If it wasn't clear from the previous sentence, the same must be done for the second if statement too.

---

Also note that using floating point for iteration is wrong. For large values, which happen below 10^12, the result will not fit into consecutive  integers and the iteration will not work correctly anymore.

A similar problem will happen with the result of the function fmodf. At some point the function will start to stop returning zeroes even for operators that are apparently divisible.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
      #include <string.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    float N;
    scanf("%f",&N);

    float nsq = N*N;
    float i;
    int count = 0;

    for(i=1.0f; i<N; i=i+1.0f)
    {
        if(!fmodf(nsq,i))

        {
           // count++;
            if(fmodf(N,i))
                count++;
        }
    }

    printf("%d", count);


    return 0;
}
```